# I have trouble with constructing a vue.js project by using npm or yarn

Tags: vue.js, npm

I have trouble with constructing a vue.js project by using npm or yarn.
the cmd: $ vue init webpack my-project

```
    # Installing project dependencies ...
    # ========================
    
    
    events.js:292
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
    
    Error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
    Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
      errno: -4058,
      code: 'ENOENT',
      syscall: 'spawn C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe;',
      path: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe;',
      spawnargs: [ '-c', 'yarn install' ]
    }
```

[the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6Im9.png)

Comment: what is  your question?

Comment: Are you intentionally using the legacy `vue init` instead of `vue create`?

Comment: The problem is that the vue.js project couldn't be created successfully and stopped running.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the steps below:

- rm -rf node_modules
- rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
- npm cache clear --force
- npm install